# How to write this SQL without duplicating the customer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has customers listed every month with and active_indicator.  For each customer, I want to pull the active indicator for just two months (Dec 2014 and Dec 2015), but when I write the below code, I get a table where each customer is listed twice. I know I can do another step to roll up the table to the customer level using max, but is there anyway to do this in one simple SQL query?

```
select distinct
     customer
    ,case when date='2015-12-01' then active_indicator else 0 end as Dec2015_active_ind
    ,case when date='2014-12-01' then active_indicator else 0 end as Dec2014_active_ind
from monthly_account_cust
where date in ('2015-12-01', '2014-12-01')
order by customer
```

Comment: Tag dbms used (MySQL or MS SQL Server?). Data type for column `date`?

Comment: Unless you aggregate this you are going to get two rows assuming there are two rows that meet the date criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure you are looking for something like this.

```
select 
    customer
    , max(case when date = '2015-12-01' then active_indicator else 0 end) as Dec2015_active_ind
    , max(case when date = '2014-12-01' then active_indicator else 0 end) as Dec2014_active_ind
from monthly_account_cust 
where date in ('2015-12-01','2014-12-01')
group by customer
order by customer
```

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, I should have known to try this.  Thanks!

Comment: If this works for you then you should consider accepting this as the answer.

Comment: LOL I don't know to be honest. I have never asked a question here. :) I think there is a button or something that only you can see to accept this an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking. And I see a button for 'Answer your Question', but nothing to accept your answer as the answer.  Maybe I do have to click on the 'Answer your question' button. Let me try....  And thanks for you help, by the way :). I see. It's the checkmark under the upvote and downvote arrows- it was such a light grey that I couldn't see it at first.